# VBA: How to use 'xltoright' and 'xldown' without using the selection method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to speed up my macro by eliminating the use of the select method. Much of my code has code like this:

```
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

how can I do the same thing without using select?

Comment: What do you do with this selection? Seems like you need to [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and similarly find the last column?

Comment: What makes you think the `Select` method is the bottleneck?

Comment: @DStanley - [because it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)?

Comment: @BigBen I am using this selection to sort my data. Depending on what happens earlier in the macro this range can change. This is why I was using the xltoright and xldown

Comment: One option is to use `Range.CurrentRegion`. A better option in my opinion is to find the last row (and similarly the last column) using the approach in the linked question from my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the range without selecting it:

```
Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
```